# Call to undefined function Project\Http\Controllers\array_sort()

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I tried to use the helper function `array_sort()`, but it returns an undefined function error. Please see my code below.

**DashboardController**

```
dd(array_sort($get_all_available_city));
```

I've created `helpers.php` by the way. Maybe it affects the functionality. But didn't override the `array_sort()`, and also I didn't put namespace on it.

**UPDATE**

I'm using laravel 7.

Comment: Because php does not have `array_sort`.

Comment: Which laravel version you are using?

Comment: @u_mulder [Laravel does](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-array-sort)

Comment: Try adding a \ before the function name, so it doesn't try to use it within the namespace.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? What makes you think that Laravel 7 contains such a method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use **string** and **array** helpers from **Laravel 6**. laravel 6 **removed** helpers function from repo. You can use
**Illuminate\Support\Arr** classes for helpers.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

Arr:::sort($get_all_available_city);
```

If you want to use helpers functions as **array_sort** then you need to install new composer package with following command :

```
composer require laravel/helpers
```

Then you can access :

```
array_sort($get_all_available_city);
```

Answer (score 5):

Laravel 7 doesn't seem to use the `array_*` calls anymore. Use [Arr::sort()](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-array-sort) instead.

```
dd(Arr::sort($get_all_available_city));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the official documentation of Laravel [here](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-array-sort)

```
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;

$array = ['Desk', 'Table', 'Chair'];

$sorted = Arr::sort($array);
```